# Grails - Variable Values At Time Of Exception

Tags: exception, grails, memory-management, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have an exception that is being thrown in Grails. Looking at the stack trace is helpful because I can see where the code bombed, but it turns out it is only bombing for one record out of hundreds, so it would be helpful to know what the values of the variables in memory are at the time of the exception. For example, in Visual Studio, when an Exception occurs, everything is paused on the line that throws the exception and all variables in memory are available to look at.

Is there anything like this for Grails (or Spring Source Tool Suite/Eclipse)? Is there a way to dump all variables to standard out? Thanks.

Comment: @proflux Please explain.

Comment: I was guessing that this is still related to your connection pooling issues, if not then sorry...

Comment: @proflux - It is unrelated. Also, I don't see how if it was that I would be yak shaving. I need to get to the bottom of the issue and am hardly blocking on this question - it would just be helpful if I had the answer, so I am putting it out there in the hopes of the future. Why sarcasm? :(

Comment: Was just kidding around man, sorry.  It would have been yak shaving because you just wanted db access, then investigate dead connections, then customize DBCP properties, then learn about pool eviction processes, now you're figuring out remote debuggers and conditional breakpoints, all when you wanted simple data access.  Bad joke, sorry man. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set an exception breakpoint, one that is triggered only when a particular type of exception is thrown.

Also, if you are using STS you can set conditional breakpoints in groovy code (and of course you can set conditional breakpoints in Java in either STS or Eclipse, but only STS allows this for Groovy).

Answer (score 1):

"Hundreds" is not a number that is unmanageable. Can you connect to your application with a remote debugger and attach a breakpoint? In Intelli-J, you can start a server in debug mode; unsure how you do it in eclipse STS/vanilla grails, aside from deploying a war into a tomcat container with remote debug connections enabled.

Comment: I am running locally so I can successfully attach breakpoints, the problem is that it only crashes on one record, so constantly hitting "next, next, next" for each record until I get to the correct record doesn't work. And if I just let it run, then I get no context as to where the crash happened.

Comment: In Eclipse you can set a conditional breakpoint. Just right click the breakpoint, go to properties and enable condition.

Comment: @proflux - A conditional breakpoint makes sense - the problem is that I don't know the condition to break on because I don't have context for the value of the variables when the crash occurs. I have to add print statements so that I can see the state of things when the crash occurred. It would be much easier if I could see all of the variables at the time of the crash before setting any breakpoints. Is anything like that possible or do I have to go down the "print variables when I found out about a crash" route?

Comment: Go to the breakpoint properties view in the debugger and [add an Exception breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-addexception_viewaction.htm).

Comment: Or you could just add a try/catch block around the failing line of code, and put a breakpoint inside the catch.

try{

}
catch( Throwable t ){
   println 'break on me'
}

An exception breakpoint is smarter, but sometimes things can be easy.